# The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]. It should be an element

Tags: php, html, css, xpath

I want to check the text at the end "Access my account" which is erroring out

```
<p class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://www.testsite/comm/index-eng.html" title="Titleblock">Home</a>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;<a href="https://testsite.com" title="Title1">Text1</a>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;<a href="index-eng.cfm?af=ZnVzZWFjdGlvbj1yZWdpc3Rlci5pbnRybyZpZD0x" title="Test Purpose">Test text</a>&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;Access my Account
</p>
```

ERROR:

> WebDriver\Exception\InvalidSelector: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//html//p[@class='breadcrumb'] /text()[last()]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you resolve a coding error if you do not provide code.

Comment: I'm using Gherkin and this is the line I'm using: And I should see "Access my Account" in the xpath "//p[@class='breadcrumb'] /text()[last()]"
Hers is how the function looks:
/**
   * Example: And I should see "Who is the Batman?" in the xpath "xpath"
   *
   *@Then I should see :arg1 in the xpath :arg2
   *@Then I see :arg1 in the xpath :arg2
   */
  public function iShouldSeeInTheXpath($text, $element) {

    $text = $this->replaceVars($text);
    $this->elementTextContainsHelper($element, $text, 'xpath'); 
  }

Answer (score 0):

Actually 'Text' is correct. The Xpath method `text()` fetches text nodes.

Your Xpath expression step by step:

- Any `p` element that is a descendant of any `html` element
  `//html//p`
- ... filter the `p` elements by the `class` attribute
  `//html//p[@class='breadcrumb']`
- ... get the text child nodes
  `//html//p[@class='breadcrumb']/text()`
- ... filter for the last node
  `//html//p[@class='breadcrumb']/text()[last()]`

Now from the error message it looks like you're using Behat. *afaik* Behat executes the expressions in the webdriver (browser or renderer). In Browser DOM the text nodes are instances of the class [Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text).

Here is a small demo in PHP DOM:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//html//p[@class='breadcrumb']/text()[last()]") as $node) {
    var_dump(get_class($node), $node->textContent);
}
```

Output:

```
string(7) "DOMText"
string(23) " > Access my Account
"
```

As you can see it matches a text node.